# Тревога на англоязычных вопросах

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

При обнаружении вопросов не на русском языке обычно поднимают тревогу "Должен быть закрыт" → "Не по теме..." и дальше указывается кастомная причина.

Почему в списке "В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса." нету других сайтов кроме Меты? Ведь если язык вопроса - английский, ему самое место на enSO.

Comment: Такая фича присутствует у модераторов. Помню, обсуждалось тут.

Comment: Странно, что это доступно только модераторам. По сути если я выбираю этот вариант, я только озвучиваю свое мнение, что этот вопрос нужно перенести. Модератору так будет легче принимать решение, если нужно только решить согласиться или нет, чем копаться в кастомных причинах и придумывать решения

Comment: У модератора обычно нет сложности с принятием решения о переносе.

Comment: @Nofate Тогда может вообще не заморачиваться, оставить в списке тревог "Требуется вмещательство модератора" :) Я понимаю, что проблем это не вызывает. Если рассмотреть один вопрос - вообще не проблема, а если их 100 - 200 неужели еще немного порядка помешает? Такие вопросы нечасты, но периодически прямо эпидемия возникает.

Answer (score 1):

> Ведь если язык вопроса - английский, ему самое место на enSO.

Это не столь однозначно. Рассмотрим причины появления таких вопросов здесь.

1. Автор как-то не заметил английского SO.

Если автор не знал о сайте enSO, значит, что он и не искал там ответ на свой вопрос. Весьма вероятно, что на сайте с 10 миллионами вопросов подобный уже есть, и ещё одна копия не нужна. Автору нужно сначала воспользоваться поиском (хотя бы автоматическим, возникающим при наборе темы вопроса) и потом уже его задавать.

2. Автор знает про enSO, но всё равно пишет здесь.

Вероятно, это потому, что автора временно лишили права задавать вопросы там, из-за низкого качества предыдущих вопросов. В этом случае перенос на enSO вряд ли уместен.

Вывод: лучше закрыть вопрос (не по теме), указать на stackoverflow.com в комментарии, и оставить дальнейшее на усмотрение автора.

Comment: 1. Вопросы-дубликаты тоже полезны. Они помогают поисковой оптимизации, создавая дополнительные формулировки проблем. 2. В сети SE десятки сайтов. Если такая проблема и возникала, её уже давно решили на уровне кода